# How to make a json from two lists in Python

Tags: python, json

assume I have two lists:

```
table_headers = ['name', 'surname']
table_data = ['andrew', 'smith', 'bob', 'richardson']
```

how can I make something like this:

```
json = {
    'name': ['andrew', 'bob'], 
    'surname': ['smith','richardson']
    }
```

Explanation of what am I doing here. I am parsing an html table to json, I didnt find the better way than to make a two lists - one is headers and one is full data and then Im gonna make a json from two lists.

Comment: That is a `dict` containing `sets`. Do you want a Python object, or a JSON-formatted string? Also, your question title says two `dicts`, but the body says two `lists`.

Comment: The formats of both the input and the desired output are asking for making you troubles. You might want to redefine then.

Comment: I am parsing html table, and I need a json representation of this table

Comment: maybe you should change parsing function and it should create dictionary.

Comment: @tkmtldn there is an issue with the question..'name' and 'surname' fields are not json objects.. i guess it should be dict / Array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably there is some function in `itertools` which could make it simpler.

I split data in smaller parts and use `zip(header, part)` to create pairs (key, val) which I addd to dictionary

```
table_headers = ['name', 'surname']
table_data = ['andrew', 'smith', 'bob', 'richardson']

len_headers = len(table_headers)
len_data = len(table_data)

result = dict()

for x in range(0, len_data, len_headers):
    for key, val in zip(table_headers, table_data[x:x+len_headers]):
        if key not in result:
            result[key] = []
        result[key].append(val)

print(result)
```

Result

```
{'name': ['andrew', 'bob'], 'surname': ['smith', 'richardson']}
```

---

**EDIT:** the same with `itertools.cycle()`

```
import itertools

table_headers = ['name', 'surname']
table_data = ['andrew', 'smith', 'bob', 'richardson']

result = dict()

for key, val in zip(itertools.cycle(table_headers), table_data):
    if key not in result:
        result[key] = []
    result[key].append(val)

print(result)
```

---

**EDIT:** and with defaultdict()

```
import itertools
import collections

table_headers = ['name', 'surname']
table_data = ['andrew', 'smith', 'bob', 'richardson']

result = collections.defaultdict(list)

for key, val in zip(itertools.cycle(table_headers), table_data):
    result[key].append(val)

print(result)

import json
print(json.dumps(result))
```

Comment: Damn, itertools to the rescue again!

Answer (score 1):

assuming that it is guaranteed the table data has the right amount of data entries to create an even number of rows (according to your header count)

You can use the good old json package, and create what you want by

```
import json 
# a very nice python package 

d = {header: table_data[i::len(table_headers)] for i,header in 
enumerate(table_headers)}


return json.dumps(d)
```

Comment: it is clever - third argument in slice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the `table_data` list, and alternatively pick values to be added to a list for `name`, and for `surname`, the values in your dictionary will be a list to contain all names and surnames

```
table_headers = ['name', 'surname']
table_data = ['andrew', 'smith', 'bob', 'richardson']

dct = {}
idx = 0
for data in table_data:
    key = table_headers[idx]
    #Create value as a list
    if key in dct.keys():
        dct[key].append(data)
    else:
        dct[key] = [data]
    #We need to make sure index of list rolls over to pick the correct element in table_data
    idx = int((idx+1)%2)
```

The output will look like.

```
{'name': ['andrew', 'bob'], 'surname': ['smith', 'richardson']}
```

Or

```
table_data = ['andrew', 'smith', 'bob', 'richardson', 'joe', 'jonas', 'matt', 'davis']
#Output
#{'name': ['andrew', 'bob', 'joe', 'matt'], 
#'surname': ['smith', 'richardson', 'jonas', 'davis']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this natively *(without any imports or special functions)* as follows:

```
table_headers = ['name', 'surname']
table_data = ['andrew', 'smith', 'bob', 'richardson']
num_of_cols = len(table_headers)
cols = [[x for x in table_data[i::num_of_cols]] for i in range(num_of_cols)]
print(dict(zip(table_headers, cols)))
## {'name': ['bob', 'andrew'], 'surname': ['smith', 'richardson']}
```

add more data:

```
table_data.extend(['john', 'doe'])
cols = [[x for x in table_data[i::num_of_cols]] for i in range(num_of_cols)]
print(dict(zip(table_headers, cols)))  
## {'name': ['andrew', 'bob', 'john'], 'surname': ['smith', 'richardson', 'doe']}
```

add more header columns:

```
table_headers = ['name', 'surname', 'middle_initial']
table_data = ['andrew', 'smith', 'a.','bob', 'richardson', 'b.']
num_of_cols = len(table_headers)
cols = [[x for x in table_data[i::num_of_cols]] for i in range(num_of_cols)]
print(dict(zip(table_headers, cols)))  
## {'name': ['andrew', 'bob'], 'surname': ['smith', 'richardson'], 'middle_initial': ['a.', 'b.']}
```